# want to check the user input and give a prompt accordingly

Tags: java, while-loop, calculator

i am making a simple calculator (in command line ). now i want my user enter any one of these four operator " +, -, * , / ".

if he enters anything else then the system should give him an error massage and ask him to enter again.

i did this for the numbers but dont know how to proceed for operators.

```
        System.out.println ("please enter a number");

        while (!get.hasNextInt ()) {

        System.out.println ("please enter a valid number");
        get.next ();

        }

   int firstNum = get.nextInt ();
```

Comment: The most simple way -> `while( !get.nextLine().equals( "*" )  || ... )` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `hasNext()` method and a simple regex:

```
get.hasNext("[+-/\\*]")
```

`[]` means it has to be one of the chars inside. You also have to use backslashes to escape `*` char, because it's a special char in regex.